# How to generate a Table of Contents (ToC) on a rendered Github Pages README.md?

Tags: github-pages, tableofcontents

Is there a way to generate a ToC on a rendered README.md hosted on Github Pages that doesn't require the use of local Jekyll plugins to generate it prior to uploading it to Github Pages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[According to this post](http://www.seanbuscay.com/blog/jekyll-toc-markdown/), all you have to do is add `{:toc}` in your markdown page at the place you want a table of contents.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, you need to add `* TOC {:toc}` once you added `markdown: kramdown` to your `_config.yml`.

Comment: Still not working. Can  you link your repo where it works?

Comment: We need to insert a new line to let TOC be rendered
`* Placeholder for Table of Content (Must not be removed) <newline>
{:toc}`

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap the ToC contents between TOC and /TOC fields in the README.md file.

Comment: 404 on https://github.com/write2sushma/TaxiDataPipeLine